# How does ssr work in meteor and why to use?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, server-side-rendering

How is meteor+react with ssr more different than same pack without ssr. What is the difference ?
For instance, does meteor render all webpages on the server ? Or is it only rendering the first page on server or something ? Why to use ssr ?

Comment: I've found ssr useful for formatting html emails on the server but there are several other applications afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the biggest reason is SEO. If SEO doesn't matter for you, you can leave it. It renders all the pages (1 route = 1 page), if the setup is correct.

It works actually very well. Based on my understanding, kadira's flow-router-ssr for react handle SSR parallel to the SPA feeling of your app. They use the checksum logic (hash that verify if the html is the same client and server), where they first render on the client like a SPA and then on server in order to have a complete source code. With kadira:dochead you can also change page title tag and some meta tags.

I have made a small demo about react, meteor and SSR. I couldn't find a lot of examples, so I did one for me in order to be able to understand it better. Check it out, run it and then analyze the source code generated.

https://github.com/LucaMele/meteor-react-ssr-app-demo

Comment: Hey man, could you please give some details on your second paragraph ? I gave up using meteor, but your answer may help many people. Especially, listing reasons to use and differences when you use ssr would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you have a SPA feeling without any compromise. Normally when you render js in the client SEO is the limit. With the isomorphic approach, you can render the same code on server side and make SEO robots happy :)

Comment: I just wrote this blog article where it gives a better overview about isomorphic apps generally. Meteor though is the major framework http://digitalmarketing.ctp.com/blog/isomorphic-web-apps-and-what-digital-marketers-should-know-about-them